# Which kind of filtering is used in SPCImage for binning?

Tags: matlab, binning

I was wondering if anyone knows which kind of filter is applied by SPCImage from the Becker & Hickl system.

I am taking some FLIM data with my system and I want to create the lifetime images. For doing so I want to bin my images in the same way as it does SPCImage, so I can increase my SN ratio. The binning goes like 1x1, 3x3, 5x5, etc. I have created the function for doing a 3x3 binning, but each time it gets more complicated...

I want to do it in MATLAB, and maybe there is already a function that can help me with this.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is old, but for anyone else wondering: You want to sum the pixels in an (2M+1) x (2M+1) neighborhood for each plane (M integer). So I am pretty sure you can go about the problem by treating it like a convolution.

```
#This is your original 3D SDT image
#I assume that you have ordered the image with spatial dimensions along the
#first and second and the time channels are the third dimension.    
img = ... #<- your 3D image goes here    

#This describes your filter. M=1 means take 1 a one pixel rect around your
#center pixel and add the values to your center, etc... (i.e. M=1 equals a
#total of 3x3 pixels accumulated)
M=2

#this is the (2D) filter for your convolution
filtr = ones(2*M+1, 2*M+1);

#the resulting binned image (3D)
img_binned = convn(img, filtr, 'same');
```

You should definitely check the result against your calculation, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to test/investigate image filter functions to apply to this king of images Fluorescence-lifetime imaging microscopy.

A median filter as showing [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=6xvcBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=FLIM%20images%20filtering&source=bl&ots=A24_SJi4i7&sig=bGXvT00IQIsdIIIRyI6s33VNxVE&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw9bCZudDRAhVSlxQKHaTqC6gQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=median%20filter&f=false) is good for smoothering things. Or a weihgted moving average filter where applied to the image erase de bright spots and only are maintained the broad features

So you need to review of the digital image processing in matlab

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I was trying different MATLAB filters, but that's not what I am looking for. They do an average of intensities with an specific weighting, depending on the filter model. I want to sum the intensity values for the specified number of pixels in order to get more counts on my intensity decay. And from there, do my fitting... So, it is different.